# OSX/ how to exit bash in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I was trying to setup home-brew and git(installed) via terminal . After i failed to install home-brew i tried to fix the errors that appeared and terminal entered bash and doesn't accept my commands . I tried quitting the terminal app or exit,logout, restart system etc.

```
Savvass-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Solen$ clear
-bash: clear: command not found
Savvass-MacBook-Pro-2:~ Solen$
```

Comment: What's the result of `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:brew :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO your path seems to be wrong. You have to fix it :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Then export it :

```
export PATH;
```

And that should be enough

Comment: @user3744039 that's how you'll learn :) consider upvote if it helped you

Comment: ofc i willi m new member i can't do yet

Comment: oh snap . when you exit the terminal application it goes the same again . same error . :/

Comment: @user3744039 : put `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`
`export PATH` to your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @user3744039 what ? How did you try to access it ?

Comment: format was necessary anyway so i did it and its ok now .